# Is all types of javascript (.js) code supported by fortify?

Tags: fortify

My application has 421 files of javascript code. When i scan them using fortify v4.30 , auditworkbench (.fpr) report shows that only 29 files of .js code has been  scanned. Is there limitation on fortify for scanning some types of .js code? If yes, what types of .js code is not supported by fortify? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Fortify should scan all of it.

When you open the fpr in auditworkbench, click the "Build Information" tab under the Project Summary to see what was scanned and what might have been missed.  Perhaps you missed a directory by accident.

If you want more assistance, tell us specific details about how you are scanning.

Comment: I have used scan wizard to create batch file. while using scan wizard, it specifies that there are 421 js files . But after the scan, fpr shows that only 29 files of js is scanned.

Comment: @Bhargavi you should be able to turn on logging in the batch file to investigate exactly what is being missed.  Add the "-logfile" command line option to the scan.  Then figure out what is being missed and consider what might be wrong, eg do the missing files come from a specific directory?